# How do I change the background of a scrollviewer

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

So I'm trying to create a custom ScrollViewer and I can't seem to figure out how to change the colors of things. As of right now it defaults to some gray value.

[image]

And this is what I'm trying to create 
[image]

I've tried changing the background properties of things such as the `RepeatButton` but that doesn't change anything unless I hover over the control.

How do I properly style it so that it looks more like the one I tried recreating?

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <!--Touchscreen & Pen-->
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>

        <!--Width-->
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="10"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{Binding Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}"/>


        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                    <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <!--Top Button-->
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="10"/>

                            <!--Fill-->
                            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*"/>

                            <!--Bottom Button-->
                            <RowDefinition MaxHeight="10"/>

                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineUpButton"
                                      Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineUpCommand}"
                                      IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowTop"
                                  Data="M 0,4 C0,4 0,6 0,6 0,6 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 3.5,2.5 7,6 7,6 7,6 7,4 7,4 7,4 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 3.5,0.5 0,4 0,4 z"
                                  Stretch="Uniform"
                                  Fill="LightGray" />
                        </RepeatButton>


                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track"
                               IsDirectionReversed="true"
                               IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                               Grid.Row="1">
                                

                                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageUpCommand}" />
                                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>

                                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                    <RepeatButton Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.PageDownCommand}" />
                                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>

                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb/>
                                </Track.Thumb>

                            </Track>

                        
                        

                        <RepeatButton x:Name="PART_LineDownButton"
                                      Command="{x:Static ScrollBar.LineDownCommand}"
                                      IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}"
                                      Grid.Row="2">
                            <Path x:Name="ArrowBottom"
                                Data="M 0,2.5 C0,2.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 0,0.5 3.5,4 3.5,4 3.5,4 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,0.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 7,2.5 3.5,6 3.5,6 3.5,6 0,2.5 0,2.5 z"
                                Stretch="Uniform"
                                Fill="LightGray" />
                        </RepeatButton>



                    </Grid>


                    <!--Triggers-->

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Did you try setting the `Background` property of the `ScrollBar`? It works using the default template.

Comment: @mm8 is that not what I did when I did this? `<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="Transparent">` I figured that was the same thing since it's in the `ControlTemplate`

Comment: Appearantly not? And why is it set to `Transparent`? Please clarify your issue. Why are you even creating a custom template in the first place?